# Calculating duration percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which logs the HTTP status code of a website whenever the status changes, so the table looks like this...

```
id    status                   date
-----------------------------------
1     404       2015-10-01 13:30:00
2     200       2015-10-02 13:30:00
3     404       2015-10-03 13:30:00
```

I want to use this data to display a table on my website showing how many times each status has been logged and the percentage duration of the status to the present time.

I have successfully managed to get the total count for each status using following query....

```
SELECT 
   `status`, 
   COUNT(*) AS `status_count` 
FROM `table_name` 
GROUP BY `status` 
ORDER BY `status`
```

...when executed gives me something like this...

```
status    status_count
----------------------
200       1
404       2
```

I would like to modify my sql add duration to my results calculated by the date column, my goal is to end up with this...

```
status    status_count    duration (%)
-----------------------------------
200       1              20
404       2              80
```

Comment: How did you get to those duration values? What calculation are you performing?

Comment: The durations in the question are examples and are incorrect. However to calculate the duration...the first ID (1) is where the duration begins and the current time is where the duration ends. The data shows that the website was 404 for exactly 24 hours before the website status changed to 200. Then the website status was 200 for 24 hours before changing to 404. 404 is the last value logged so is still 404 to the current time.

Comment: so the correct result should be 404 `66%` and 200 `33%` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza not necessarily, the duration of the last entry is calculated to the present date.

Comment: Well good I ask, becase that was not obvious in your question

Comment: It seems you are count number of hours and showing %. In that case, I would recommend to store hours in your table instead of date and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2242/1)

```
SELECT t1.status
      ,COUNT(t1.id) as status_count
      ,SUM(IF(t2.date IS NULL, NOW(), t2.date)-t1.date) / (NOW()-t3.start_date) as duration
  FROM table_name t1
       LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t1.id = (t2.id - 1)
      ,(SELECT MIN(date) as start_date FROM table_name) t3
GROUP BY t1.status
```

Comment: I like your sql because is more efficient, but your is returning a different result than mine, please could you double check with the fiddle demo. I validate mine using excel.

Comment: Juan, thank you so much for creation of fiddle demo. Based on data from it 404 was 1 day (07/01-02) and almost 18 days (07/03-21). So it is a little bit less than 19 days. Status 200 was 1 day (07/02-03). So approximately Result should be for 404 - little bit less than 95% (0.9498 based on fiddle demo result)  and for 200 a little bit more than 5% (0.0502). Am I right?

Comment: @nick  Thank you very much! This is the code I have implemented What should I do if I want to filter by date?

Comment: If you want to add filter by date, you can use something like the following query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2242/39

Answer (score 1):

Mine is more complicated than nick but give a different result.
And i try it on excel to verify values are correct.

I start date with `2015-07-01 13:30:00` so `NOW()` function can work

That mean seconds are

```
404 | 86400    1 day   | 0.05101 
200 | 86400    1 day   | 0.05101   
404 | 1521138 17 days  | 0.89799 
total 1693938
```

Final Result

```
404 | 2 | 0.94899 
200 | 1 | 0.05101
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ec8f/8)

```
SELECT  status, Count(status), SUM(secdiff) / MAX(sectotal) as porcentage
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         h1.status, 
         h2.dateupdate d1, 
         h1.dateupdate d2,
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,h1.dateupdate, h2.dateupdate) secdiff,
         TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                       (SELECT MIN(dateupdate) from logHttp), 
                       NOW()) sectotal
    FROM 
        logHttp as h1 INNER JOIN
        (
          (Select * from logHttp)
          union
          (select MAX(id) +1, 0, NOW() from logHttp)
        ) as h2
        On h1.id + 1 = h2.id     
 ) as t1
 group by status;
```

Comment: your query is perfect for what I need, however I have more columns in the data table than shown in my example and this is causing the following error: "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aed7d/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select a.*,(a.status_count/b.tot)*100 as duration_per from (SELECT 
       `status`, 
       COUNT(*) AS `status_count` 
    FROM `table_name` 
    GROUP BY `status` 
    ORDER BY `status`) a join (select count(*) as tot from `table_name`) b
```

Comment: I think you are calculating status instead of date

Comment: Yes I think this is what desired by @itsliamoco

Comment: and @itsliamoco provided us only one time. how we can calculate the datetime difference?

Comment: You calculate the time difference between one row and the next.. and the last with NOW()

Comment: if there will be more than one 404 then from which time to NOW()

Comment: status A to status B calculate time ... the status B to Status A ... then status A to NOW().